# Weather data is not displaying in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

This is the code that is not working. I am getting a typerror called "cannot read the property of undefined ("temp")".

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import "./css/style.css";
import { BiStreetView } from "react-icons/bi";

const Tempapp = () => {
  const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchApi = async () => {
      const url = `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weatherq=${search}nits=metric&APPID=83ea3057047027c6c4521d32d69250a0`;
      const res = await fetch(url);
      const resjson = await res.json();
      // console.log(resjson);
      setCity(resjson);
    };
    fetchApi();
  }, [search]);

  return (
    <>
      <div className="box">
        <div className="inputData">
          <input
            type="search"
            className="inputField"
            value={search}
            placeholder="Enter city"
            onChange={(event) => setSearch(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>

        {city ? (
          <div className="info">
            <h1 className="temp">{city.main.temp} °Cel</h1>
            <h1 className="weather">{city.weather[0].main}</h1>

            <h3 className="tempmin_max">
              Min : {city.main.temp_min} °Cel | Max : {city.main.temp_max} °Cel
            </h3>
          </div>
        ) : (
          <p>Not relevant</p>
        )}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tempapp;
```

I am using react js and I am unable to display the weather.
this is my code, in the console it is showing "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'temp')"
How can I solve this please help!
I can display like this {setCity(resjson.main)}
but unable to do like this {setCity(resjson)}
Want to display the weather and temperature and minimum and maximum temperature.

API Data:

```json
{
  "coord": {
    "lon": 73.8333,
    "lat": 15.4833
  },
  "weather": [{
    "id": 804,
    "main": "Clouds",
    "description": "overcast clouds",
    "icon": "04n"
  }],
  "base": "stations",
  "main": {
    "temp": 298.95,
    "feels_like": 299.75,
    "temp_min": 298.95,
    "temp_max": 298.95,
    "pressure": 1011,
    "humidity": 83,
    "sea_level": 1011,
    "grnd_level": 1011
  },
  "visibility": 10000,
  "wind": {
    "speed": 2.94,
    "deg": 303,
    "gust": 4.1
  },
  "clouds": {
    "all": 86
  },
  "dt": 1663596174,
  "sys": {
    "country": "IN",
    "sunrise": 1663548808,
    "sunset": 1663592632
  },
  "timezone": 19800,
  "id": 1260607,
  "name": "Panjim",
  "cod": 200
}
```

Comment: Can you export and share the "city" object? Is city.main defined?

Comment: You've really mangled the snippet markdown of your question.  How did you do that?  Can you edit your question and clean it up or do you want someone to try to fix it for you?  It's a little hard to tell if this is actually intended to be a runnable snippet.

Comment: @OfirBaruch city is a state and i am storing response in city state.

Comment: @Wyck I have edited it, please solve my issue.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You state it works when you correctly set the city with the data you want, but you explicitly want to set *different* data to `city`? That means all your `city` property accesses would need to be prefixed with `main` (if I'm reading the code right). What's the main issue?

Comment: Tangential: it's *way* easier to think about code when only the necessary code is shown, e.g., all the date/time stuff doesn't matter (and it's hard to read because there's a giant wad of code inside string interpolation--I'd consider moving that into someplace less intrusive.

Comment: @DaveNewton no i don't want to set different data to city. But I want to use the full information provided by the api  and I am unable to do that.

Comment: @DaveNewton sorry for large code. By the way I've edited it once again just now. Please solve my issue

Comment: @MustafaMulla What *didn't* work when you set the data you *want* to city and fix the code to refer to the proper nested data?

Comment: @DaveNewton like I am able use "setCity(resjson.main)". But unable to use "setCity(resjson)". In the sense I am unable to use full data from api but able to use part of data.

Comment: @DaveNewton please see the api data I have added and have a look at the line just above it.

Comment: @MustafaMulla ... If you `setCity` with `resjson` can you not access the `main` data via `main.temp`, for example? You can't have it both ways: if you want all the data you need to set all the data. If you set all the data then you need to access it in the shape it's actually in.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes I tried it but it is getting me typerror of cannot read property of undefined temp. How can I solve this?

Comment: I would start by including the code that actually doesn't work, not the code that does. If the data is present, and it's set to state, it should be accessible like any other object.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your API fetching. When I tried [running your app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-starter-typescript-1kcevg?file=Temperature.tsx,App.tsx), I faced

```
TypeError: Failed to fetch
```

And when I browsed through the Open Weather API documentation, I found the standard way of [calling their APIs](https://openweathermap.org/current#geo) quite different than yours. Please make sure you have appropriately set up your API keys and access.

Comment: Coz I haven't shared my api od there, if you want I can share it. Please run and solve it

Comment: I have added api id just now please run and see what is the problem.

Comment: it is the same.